# How to use a variable ForegroundColor with write-host onto Start-job

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I'm stuck into a little problem that I don't understand, here is a simplified version of my code :

```
[hashtable] $result_color = @{
    OPENED  = [ConsoleColor]::green;
    FERME   = [ConsoleColor]::red
}

$job = Start-Job -Name "test" -Scriptblock {
    Write-Host "Test text" -ForegroundColor $result_color.OPENED
} -ArgumentList $result_color

Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
Receive-Job $job
```

I get the following error :

> Unable to bind "ForegroundColor" parameter to target. Exception when defining "ForegroundColor": "Unable to convert Null value to "System.ConsoleColor" type due to invalid enumeration values."

I also tried this :

```
[hashtable] $result_color= @{
    OPENED  = [System.ConsoleColor] "green";
    CLOSED  = [System.ConsoleColor] "red"
}

$job = Start-Job -Name "test" -Scriptblock {
    Write-Host "Test text" -ForegroundColor $result_color.OPENED
} -ArgumentList $result_color

Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
Receive-Job $job
```

But same error... Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Change `$result_color.OPENED` inside the scriptblock to `$args[0].OPENED`

Comment: Alternatively, you can make do without a parameter altogether, via the `$using:` scope: `$job = Start-Job -Name "test" -Scriptblock { Write-Host "Test text" -ForegroundColor $using:result_color.OPENED }`

Comment: Thanks ! I just forgot the "args[x]"... Thanks everyone for your help and alternatives !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either do what [Mathias commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208408/how-to-use-a-variable-foregroundcolor-with-write-host-onto-start-job#comment120549373_68208408), OR add a param block into your scriptblock and use the `-ArgumentList` parameter to feed it the correct value like

```
$job = Start-Job -Name "test" -Scriptblock {
    param($color)
    Write-Host "Test text" -ForegroundColor $color
} -ArgumentList $result_color.OPENED
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just forgot the "args[x]"... Thanks everyone for your help !