# Foregroundcolor is not being set correctly inside ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, colors, powershell-2.0, write-host

Edit: The issue I'm facing is from an ADO pipeline
I have a ps1 script that does parallel execution. I want to set the foreground color to green but the code is not working when I am setting it inside the ScriptBlock

```
$color=[System.ConsoleColor]"Green"
$MainScriptblock = {
    Param($Repo,$CloningPath,$GitURL,$SourceBranch,$DestinationBranch,$ReleaseTag,$modulepath,$color)       
Write-Host "*****************************************************************" -ForegroundColor $color

}

foreach ($Repository in $ReposToBranch) {           
$job = Start-Job -Name $Repository -InitializationScript $InitScriptblock -ScriptBlock $MainScriptblock -ArgumentList $Repository,$Global:CloningPath,$GitURL, $SourceBranch, $DestinationBranch,$ReleaseTag,$modulepath,$color;
}
```

I tried using Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host but made no difference
I came across this post and the implementation is similar to mine. [How to use a variable ForegroundColor with write-host onto Start-job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208408/how-to-use-a-variable-foregroundcolor-with-write-host-onto-start-job)

What could be wrong with my approach

Comment: Inject ANSI escape sequences to your string instead of using `-ForegroundColor`. i.e.: `Write-Host "$($PSStyle.Foreground.Green)******$($PSStyle.Reset)"` if you're using pwsh 7. otherwise you need to `Write-Host "$([char] 27)[32m******$([char] 27)[0m"`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**:

Your issue isn't related to *jobs*, it is **related to use of PowerShell in a  *CI/CD environment*** (an Azure DevOps pipeline in your case) or, more generally, **when calling the *PowerShell CLI*** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) **and *capturing its output***.

In that case, all output is invariably *stringified*, during which the coloring of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is currently (as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x) invariably *lost*.

A simple way to illustrate the problem from inside PowerShell:

```bash
# Due to capturing the output (piping to another command), the
# coloring is lost.
powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green green!' | Write-Output
```

[GitHub issue #20171](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20171) suggests *preserving* the coloring, which would necessitate *automatically* embedding [ANSI/VT escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) that correspond to the `-Foreground` / `-Background` arguments in the output text, as shown *manually* below.

---

**Workaround**:

As [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) notes, **you'll have to embed the ANSI/VT escape sequences *yourself*, instead of using the `-ForegroundColor` / `-BackgroundColor` parameters** of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host):

In *Windows PowerShell*:

```bash
Write-Host "$([char] 27)[32m******$([char] 27)[m"
```

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can more conveniently use the [`$PSStyle` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_Variables#psstyle):

```bash
# PS v7.2+ only
Write-Host "$($PSStyle.Foreground.Green)******$($PSStyle.Reset)"
```